# c++ issue passing information to pthreads

Tags: c++, pthreads, corruption

The issue I am having is that printf debug statements in showData() will give me nonsensical numbers. i.e.: the thread_id is -1781505888. 
If I insert the printf statements in createThreads() right after I set the values of thread_id, startIndex, and stopIndex then the values will print correctly. Somehow data is being corrupted when i pass threadData as an argument to pthread_create or when I read data from threadArg in showData(). Also, the values of N and k can be assumed to be integers with the remainder of N/k being 0. All help is appreciated.

edit: Also if it provides any extra information- when I run this on the same input I will get different output each time I run it. sometimes nonsensical numbers, sometimes all values print as 0, and once in a while it seg faults.

```
void createThreads(int k){
struct threadData threadData;
int numThreads = k;
int i = 0;
int err = 0;

pthread_t *threads = static_cast<pthread_t*>(malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * numThreads));
for(i = 0;i<numThreads;i++){
    struct threadData threadData;
    threadData.thread_id = i;
    threadData.startIndex = ((N/k)*i);
    if(i == numThreads -1){
        threadData.stopIndex = ((N/k)*(i+1))-1;
    }
    else{
        threadData.stopIndex = ((N/k)*(i+1));
    }



    err = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, showData, (void *)&threadData); 


    if(err != 0){
        printf("error creating thread\n");
    }
}
}

void *showData(void *threadArg){
    struct threadData *threadData;
    threadData = (struct threadData *) threadArg;

    printf("thread id : %d\n", threadData->thread_id);
    printf("start: %d\n", threadData->startIndex);
    printf("stop : %d\n", threadData->stopIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`threadData` is local to your for loop... it goes out of scope on each iteration, so a pointer to it is not valid in your `showData()` routine.  You could instead allocate it dynamically and `delete` it at the end of `showData`.

You probably want to return the `threads` data to `createThreads`' caller too, so it can `join` the threads to await completion of the `showData` "work".

Example:

```
...
for(i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i)
{
    struct threadData* threadData = new struct threadData;
    threadData->thread_id = i;
    threadData->startIndex = ((N/k)*i);
    if(i == numThreads -1){
        threadData->stopIndex = ((N/k)*(i+1))-1;
    }
    else{
        threadData->stopIndex = ((N/k)*(i+1));
    }

    err = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, showData, (void*)threadData); 

    if(err != 0){
        printf("error creating thread\n");
        exit(1); // probably not worth trying to continue...
    }
    return threads;
}

void *showData(void *threadArg){
    struct threadData* threadData = (struct threadData*)threadArg;

    printf("thread id : %d\n", threadData->thread_id);
    printf("start: %d\n", threadData->startIndex);
    printf("stop : %d\n", threadData->stopIndex);

    delete threadData;
}
```

Comment: @jeremy: some illustrative code added.  I'd recommend you choose identifiers for `struct`s and `class`s that are capitalised differently from your variables... e.g. `ThreadData`... that way you don't have to litter to the code with e.g. `struct threadData threadData;` and can just say `ThreadData threadData;` - makes it clearly when you're referring to the class vs. an instance thereof.

Comment: I am still receiving fairly random numbers from my printf statements after following your suggestions

Comment: @jeremy Can you append your complete current code to your question?  Nothing more I can tell you without that....

Comment: @jeremy I actually started typing for you to check this even before you posted your code, then thought it was too speculative - it's `(void *)&threadData` - you forgot to remove the `&`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. Working properly now